# Add a Validator 2 times in an Element on Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-validate

I made a Validator that receives a class instance and a function name and then executes it.

This is usefull for execute many custom validations through database table mappers.

The problem is that I can't add this validator more than one time to a Element and I need to do it...

**Example:**

I've a login form that have a username and password elements. For username, I need to verify via this Validator if it already exists in the Database and, if it exists, I need to verify if the selected account is activated...

I know that I could make just one function to receive the result for both but, my Validator should only return one error message...

**Here's the constructor of the Validator:**

```
/**
 *$class is a class instance
 *$function is the function name to execute in the class
 *$invalidReturns specifies when the validator should return the error message (default is when the function returns null, false or empty string)
 *$tokens are used as parameters of the function to execute
*/
public function __construct($class, $function, $invalidReturns=null, $tokens=null)
{
    $this->class = $class;
    $this->function = $function;
    $this->tokens = $tokens;
    $this->returns = $invalidReturns;
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Is there a way to create a Class in PHP with dynamic name? Is there a way to add a same class Validator to an element in Zend or should I change my Valitor to return more then one message and pass them in the constructor?

Comment: Did you already take a look to Zend_Validate_Callback? This looks very simular to what you wants so could save you work and might work multiple times to (i'm not sure).

Comment: I didn't know that but, as I've seen, this only works with methods that only have one parameter (the element itself). My Validator works with functions that have more than one parameter (Example: function to verify if the selected username exists for a specific email (both inserted by the user)). I'm trying to change my own Validator to receive more than one message. If it works, I close this question. Also I will upvote your answer because it solves most cases like mine.

Comment: Passing more variables to your callback is not a problem, you can define a options parameter as argument $validator = new Zend_Validate_Callback(array('callback' => array($this, 'someExample'), 'options' => array('arg1' => 'test', 'arg2', 'etc')); Something like that should work. I'm not sure if you can define more messages..

Comment: Hmm, I see... So the this Zend_Validate_Callback is almost identical to the Validator that I made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution provided by Kees Schepers in the comments should work but, as I did my own "Zend_Validate_Callback", I could change the way it works to allow the definition of more than one message.

Now it's working well =)

Anyway, thanks Kees Schepers. Next time, I will use Zend_Validate_Callback instead of doing a lot of more work x).